# Android - Null Pointer Exception error when launching new activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, nullpointerexception

The following code accepts an intent from a listview that contains a listview. This activity captures the title of the listview selected, and then launches this activity, passing a string intent of the title. Before this activity loads, it crashes and logcat reports a 'Null Pointer Exception'. The items in the string array are as follows:

```
[0][.] = Id, starting at 0
[1][.] = name, the name as shown on the listview
[2][.] = description
```

ect

This is the view activity

```
 public class view extends HomeActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = b.getString("index");


        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        RatingBar rb = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);

        int tempPosition = 0;
        int intvalue = 0;

        //Find the id of the item[0], given the name[1]
        while(value!=Challenges.chalarray[tempPosition][1]){
            if (Challenges.chalarray[tempPosition][1].contains(value)){
                String s = Challenges.chalarray[tempPosition][0];
                intvalue = Integer.parseInt(s);
            }
            tempPosition = tempPosition + 1;
        }


        title.setText(Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][1]);
        description.setText(Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][2]);
        String temp = Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][4];
        String s1 = Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][3];
        float f1 = Float.parseFloat(s1);
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier (temp, "drawable", "com.tim.listviewapp");
        iv.setImageResource(resourceId);
        rb.setRating(f1);
```

I'm 99% sure the sending side is correct, so I have not posted it. I am happy to post it if you guys think theres something wrong with it. Thank you HEAPS!

EDIT: 
Logcat:

```
    01-02 03:18:48.789: D/AndroidRuntime(1194): Shutting down VM
01-02 03:18:48.789: W/dalvikvm(1194): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4b00b90)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194): Process: com.tim.listviewapp, PID: 1194
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tim.listviewapp/com.tim.listviewapp.View}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at com.tim.listviewapp.View.onCreate(View.java:35)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-02 03:18:48.849: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     ... 11 more
```

EDIT AGAIN: (For Babibu)

```
01-02 03:51:15.760: W/dalvikvm(883): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a1db90)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883): Process: com.tim.listviewapp, PID: 883
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tim.listviewapp/com.tim.listviewapp.View}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at com.tim.listviewapp.View.onCreate(View.java:44)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
01-02 03:51:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(883):  ... 11 more
01-02 03:51:19.270: I/Process(883): Sending signal. PID: 883 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post your Logcat

Comment: log cat required. you might be confident but  we are not .

Comment: Why you have extended the `HomeActivity` ? @TimJ

Comment: Your logcat is not full, please post the full logcat

Comment: Post line where you got NPW.

Comment: Is **HomeActivity** is your Basic Activity??

Comment: This is the full logcat, lines in logcat previous to this are for previous launches of the application

Comment: Yes, all HomeActivity cotains is a button to start the application. Basically, I didn't know what to extend, so I tried that..

Comment: what you have at line 35 in View.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Challenges.chalarray` is not initialised, so the first time you're trying to access it you get null. Change the initialisation to:

```
public class Challenges {
    public static String[][] chalarray = {
        { "0", "Challenge1", "Sample Description", "5", "base" },
        { "1", "Challenge2?", "Sample Description", "4", "base"},
        //etc
    };
}
```

Also, I'd change the `while loop` to run through all the elements in chalarray and to break from the loop when correct id is found:

```
while(tempPosition < Challenges.chalarray.length) {
    if (Challenges.chalarray[tempPosition][1].contains(value)) {
        String s = Challenges.chalarray[tempPosition][0];
        intvalue = Integer.parseInt(s);
        break;
    }
    tempPosition = tempPosition + 1;
}
```

Just keep in mind that if the id is not found, intvalue will be 0 from initialization, so in the following lines make sure you handle that, in other words, do you want to display the details of the element 0:

```
title.setText(Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][1]);
description.setText(Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][2]);
String temp = Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][4];
String s1 = Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][3];
```

Comment: Yay! No more nullpointerexception error. But now I have an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: If tempPosition or intvalue are bigger than 98 (if you kept the original size of your array, that is 99), then you will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, so check your `while` loop first, then check what is the value of intvalue.

Comment: Great, what's on that line? Again, check tempPosition and intvalue if they are bigger than 98 (or whatever number of 'rows'-1 you have in your chalarray).

Comment: Thank you, I will check and report back

Comment: Alright, the problem is with 'intvalue'. Whatever number of indexes are in the array, is the number that is given by log cat. e.g.

`01-02 04:46:50.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
`
Will show when I only have 4 items in the array.. What does this mean?

Comment: It means you're accessing element at index 4, whereas the array has length of 4 (so indexes are 0 to 3). See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize, check your code

Comment: what should be initialize? Can you explain more clear

Answer (score 0):

Unfortanatly the log cat is not helping us.

Try running this code:

```
public class view extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = b.getString("index");


        TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        RatingBar rb = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);

        isNull(title);
        isNull(description);
        isNull(iv);
        isNull(rb);

        int tempPosition = 0;
        int intvalue = 0;

        isNull(Challenges.chalarray);
        isNull(Challenges.chalarray[0]);
        isNull(Challenges.chalarray[1]);

        //Find the id of the item[0], given the name[1]
        while(value!=Challenges.chalarray[tempPosition][1]){
            if (Challenges.chalarray[tempPosition][1].contains(value)){
                String s = Challenges.chalarray[tempPosition][0];
                intvalue = Integer.parseInt(s);
            }
            tempPosition = tempPosition + 1;
        }

        isNull(Challenges.chalarray[0]);
        isNull(Challenges.chalarray[1]);
        isNull(Challenges.chalarray[2]);
        isNull(Challenges.chalarray[3]);
        isNull(Challenges.chalarray[4]);

        title.setText(Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][1]);
        description.setText(Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][2]);
        String temp = Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][4];
        String s1 = Challenges.chalarray[intvalue][3];
        float f1 = Float.parseFloat(s1);
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier (temp, "drawable", "com.tim.listviewapp");
        iv.setImageResource(resourceId);
        rb.setRating(f1);
    }

    private void isNull(Object title) {
        if(title == null){
            Log.d("MyTag", "this is your error:");
            new Throwable("Exception log").printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

I added a `testNull` method here to help us find the problem. How ever a much better solution would be if you could just debug it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'm really sorry though, I'm new to Android programming. What do you mean by the views are null? The XML document contains all of them, with the correct referenced id. Again, thank you so much

Comment: @TimJ The problem is with your logcat, you only show us part of it so I can't tell what is the problem. If your ids are correct than option 1 is not your problem.

Comment: I have added more of the Logcat, sorry, some of it didnt copy properly before.

Comment: I have also added the array

Comment: Thank you Babibu, I have tried your code and still hit the same error, as there is not enough room in the comments section, I have added the updated logcat into my question. Hopefully it can help, I have no idea what is going on with it. Thank you